# Is there a way to create loop for plotyoutput

Tags: r, shiny

I have a dynamic condition where I need to create fluidrows dynamically

```
cname <- c("A","B")
lapply(cname, function(name){paste0("column(6,",paste0("plotlyOutput(","'",name,"'","))"))})

[[1]]
[1] "column(6,plotlyOutput('A'))"

[[2]]
[1] "column(6,plotlyOutput('B'))"
```

Expected output

I need to incorporate Fluidrows here created as the beginning

```
fluidRow(column(6,plotlyOutput("A")),
column(6,plotlyOutput("B")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for `purrr::exec` paired with `!!!` operator to splice a list as arguments.

Example app:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)



cname <- c("A", "B")

plotly_outputs <- map(cname, ~ column(width = 6, plotlyOutput(outputId = .)))

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  exec("fluidPage", !!!plotly_outputs)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  walk(cname, ~ {
    output[[.]] <<- renderPlotly({
      plt <- mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) +
        geom_point()
      ggplotly(plt)
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```